# I get error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) when trying to import FS in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to import FS in my .js file.   This line of code is giving me the 404 error.   If I look at the explorer in VSCode I see @types.   And if I ctrl click on the link it take me to the file.   It seems the @types may be an issue because as I type the link @types doesn't show up after ./node_modules/....If I type in @types/ I do get node and then fs.js as an option in the autofill dropdown

```
import { readdirSync } from './node_modules/@types/node/fs.js';
```

Is there a reason why the compiler doesn't see the @types even though it appears in the explorer and the link goes to the correct file?

Comment: isn't it just `import { readdirSync } from "node:fs"` - what environment has node built-ins in `node_modules` folder?

Comment: thank you for your reply Jaromanda    I tried your suggestion and get this error: Access to script at 'node:fs' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.

Comment: I've also tried import { readdirSync } from "fs"  and get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: are you trying to use "fs" in a browser script?

Comment: yes it is running in a browser.  I actually never knew anything about FS.   I am using html2pdf to create a pdf file.   That part worked.  However, when I went to upload that file to firebase storage that did not work.

Comment: a browser can't access node internal modules - since it is a browser, node nodejs

Comment: Thank you so much.   Is there anyway to upload a file from a web browser? I was actually surprised that I was able to create the pdf file and store it in downloads folder.  But I really need to be able to upload the file to firebase storage

Comment: yes, you send the data to your server - which would perform the required database operation

Comment: Thank you so much.   I figured it out.   I don't need to use FS at all.   I went with the File API.  I was hoping i can avoid having the user have to select a file but I think I may have figured out a way to make it pretty much error proof on their end.   Thank you very much for your help Jaromanda X!